# Extract number and a character from sting using regex

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to extract the number along with 'x'from string:
1. "KAWAN (FRZ) LACHA FLACKEY PARATHA 8X25X80 GM" or
2. G.G. HOT SEV 20X285GM" using function: but it returns only last number with "x". Expected output is 2X25X or 20X... also is it possible to store the string without the extracted value using the same function?:

```
Public Function getNumber(strInput As String) As Variant
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim matches As Object

regex.Pattern = "(\d??[x|X])"
regex.Global = False

Set matches = regex.Execute(strInput)
If matches.Count = 0 Then
    getNumber = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Else
    getNumber = matches(0).Value
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following pattern for your regular expression...

```
regex.Pattern = "((\d{1,2}[xX])+)"
```

**Results**

[image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6yUSqw/1)

By the way, since you're using early binding, you can declare `matches` as `MatchCollection` instead of `Object`.

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate your kind help. It works great only problem it's giving when there is space in between number and X. I tried using ? but got the execution error.

Comment: In that case, you can use  `((\d{1,2} ?[xX])+)`.  If this doesn't return the desired results, I would suggest that you edit your question, and include some examples along with the expected results.

Comment: Wow it worked, I had tried it without giving space after braces :)... Thank you so much... you guys rock.

Comment: This is only case where it fails now: GOLD PINEAPPLE 48 PKTS X 66.72 GM

Comment: @Vakhs In your answer there was not enough information to infer this last case you commented, next time you post a question here be sure to post all the required test cases or formulate your question better so that people can answer it more accurately

Comment: Try changing it to `((\d{1,2} ?[a-zA-Z]* ?[xX])+)` .

Comment: Thank you so much Domenic. It works perfect. God bless you all! All you guys are doing a stupendous job of  helping others. Thank you! Thank you!! Thank you!!   Sorry for all the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

Tru changing your regular expression to `(\d*)[xX]`, this will capture none or more numbers followed by an X and put the numbers in a group. You can test this regex in [this website](https://regex101.com/r/XGy6x5/4), you'll see that applying this regex in your first exemple `KAWAN (FRZ) LACHA FLACKEY PARATHA 8X25X80 GM` it will capture `8X` and `25X` and each match will have the `8` and `25` as its group, respectively

Comment: PS.: note the use of the global flag in the website, without it the regex will only catch the first match

Comment: Thank you but I am getting Method "Execute" of object IRegExp2 failed". Also is there a way we can store the string without the extracted value?

Comment: This also matches a simple pipe character `|`: https://regex101.com/r/XGy6x5/3

Comment: @Vakhs you can using the [Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.replace?view=netcore-3.1), replacing the regex matches with a empty string

Comment: @HenriqueSabino Replace works like a charm... Thank you! Thank you!! Thank you!!